# What's with error 1241 Operand should contain 1 column?

Tags: mysql

I have a class project and I want to rank my data according to their score
but every time I run this query on mysql it always gives me error 1241.

Any thoughts on what's causing these?

here is my query:

```
SELECT
(SELECT gen_cityname, 
        SUM(scc_bgyscoretotal) as score, 
        @curRank := @curRank + 1 AS rank 
FROM bgyprofile b, (SELECT @curRank := 0) r 
WHERE gen_provname = bgyprofile.gen_provname 
GROUP BY gen_incomeyr, gen_cityname 
ORDER BY score asc) AS provranks
FROM bgyprofile 
GROUP BY bgyprofile.gen_incomeyr, bgyprofile.gen_cityname
```

Comment: I'm trying to rank the score column

Comment: please provide some sample data for all the relevant tables and expected output. It would be best if you could setup https://www.db-fiddle.com

Comment: Subquery in `SELECT` can only return a scalar value.  Your subquery returns a table.  Google some subquery tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

it gives error 1241 because your query has the form

```
SELECT (SELECT column1, column2 FROM t2) FROM t1;
```

(https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/subquery-errors.html)

As they say in comments sample data and an explenation of what you expect would be very useful. Maybe the first step is to change the query starting with SELECT * and moving the SELECT between brackets after the FROM, but, I repeat, I need some more information to understand the right way.